# Are these attack attempts to my PC stopped by ufw?

Tags: ufw

The router re-directs several ports to my PC.

I checked ufw.log and found many entries that look like attacks from other countries. I checked the IP and they are reported as abusive/ hacking.

These are example lines from ufw.log

```
Oct 14 08:14:43  kernel: [252337.271031] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC= **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:** SRC=213.226.123.38 DST=10.0.1.28 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=56509 PROTO=TCP SPT=49810 DPT=3389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Oct 14 08:53:14  kernel: [254647.921581] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC= **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:** SRC=79.124.62.130 DST=10.0.1.28 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=22278 PROTO=TCP SPT=46668 DPT=3389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Oct 14 09:02:13  kernel: [255187.278445] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC= **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:** SRC=64.62.197.16 DST=10.0.1.28 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=12602 PROTO=UDP SPT=36769 DPT=3389 LEN=24 
Oct 14 09:14:45  kernel: [255939.716660] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC= **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:** SRC=185.156.74.31 DST=10.0.1.28 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=10729 PROTO=TCP SPT=53080 DPT=3389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

After this, I removed many of the redirection ports from the router to my PC.

So, my question is: Are these attacks? If so, is UFW enough to protect from these attacks? are these normal, meaning, are these attackers screening the web, and everyone has them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Are these attacks?**

Probably yes.

**If so, is UFW enough to protect from these attacks?**

In general yes, but be careful with the running services behind these ports. My first recommandation would be to have secure passwords, as these attacks are very often bruteforce. If possible, use a local VPN server in your home, instead of opening too many ports.

**are these normal[...]and everyone has them?**

Yes, it is normal, I think everyone has these attacks, particulary when using default ports. For example if you want less attacks on ssh, change the port forwarding rule to expose a random port you choose (63721 for example), that will redirect on your local 22 port. For more security on ssh, prefer public key authentication instead of traditionnal password.

Oh, and an other tip:
You can use fail2ban, in order to automatically ban malicious IPs.

More informations [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/675010/how-to-secure-your-linux-computer-with-fail2ban/).

Comment: Thanks! I feel better. My mistake not changing the RDP port. Other ports were already changed. I have to say, I have also activated faillock which may help with the brute-force attacks. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm happy this helps you... For example, in my case, I had about 2000 logins attempts on a personal ssh server. After that I set up a VPN server, fail2ban and public key authentication. I feel better like that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is: Are these attacks?

On the internet there are literally tens of millions of compromised devices (PCs, laptops, servers, routers, IoTs) which simply scan all the [public IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_address) for open ports. I'm not sure about IPv6 because it contains too many addresses, so simply enumerating them could take too much traffic and time and render them a lot less effective.

Once an open port is found, those devices will try to either guess the password or use known vulnerabilities for this port/service (as many devices on the internet are not [properly] updated).

I wouldn't call them "attacks" per se. For me an "attack" is when someone targets you *specifically* in order to compromise your device/get unauthorized access. What you see is *automated* scanners/password brute forcing devices.

> If so, is UFW enough to protect from these attacks?

UFW is a high level daemon which manages iptables/nftables rules, but those rules are enough.

> are these normal, meaning, are these attackers screening the web, and everyone has them?

Exactly. At my company we have dozens of servers where each receives literally *thousands* of such penetration attempts *daily*.

Comment: Thanks! it is scary seeing you are scanned from other countries from other continents!  After reading the two answers here I feel better. I think ufw, faillock, redirecting should be good enough. I just discover the ufw.log and I think it is also a good tool to be sure you are not showing too much! Thanks again

Comment: Just don't forward any ports you're not 100% sure about. Also it helps using non-standard ports, e.g. 1022 instead of 22 for SSH (sshd). That will reduce the number of hacking attempts ~tenfold. If you keep your system up to date and have strong passwords there's little danger in forwarding everything you desire as long as it's properly configured. Nowadays in Linux most services are properly configured out of the box, so with default settings there's not too much danger.